# Код выводит не то, что предполагалось

Tags: c++

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int i = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if (i > 4)
            break;
        cout << i << endl;
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Почему-то выводит

```
0
1
2
3
4

Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...
```

После того, как i становится 4, цикл завершается и не проходит через cout, в чем я ошибся?

Comment: Такого рода вопросы должны решаться самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3):

Всё правильно он выводит. После того как вывел 4, следующая строка увеличивает `i` до 5, потом переход на начало цикла, и выход по условию.

Answer (score 2):

Код работает именно так, как написан: как только переменная i становится равной 5 цикл завершается на строке "if( i > 4 ) break;" и ничего не выводит. А что ожидалось-то?

P.S. Pls, объясните, что за манера пошла в конце писать "system("pause")"? Вопрос не зачем (наверняка потому что окошко с cmd схлопывается, гы-гы), а почему именно так...

Comment: Как преподаватель сказал, так и пишем.

Answer (score 1):

Выходит из цикла сразу же после break'а, если хотите чтобы проходил до конца, то и проверку выполняйте в самом конце.

Comment: так если сразу же выходит из цикла то почему пишет 0 1 2 3 4, если когда i становится 4 то операция cout<<4 не должна выполнятся?

Comment: 4 не больше 4-х, потому проходит 4

Comment: все, понял

Comment: @rinat_h, эта операция уже выполнилась, иначе как бы ты увидел `4` на экране?

Answer (score 0):

Все просто,компилятор выполняет действия последовательно, соответственно вам надо переместить break; в другое место после вывода i, а то так получается что вначале вы выходите из цикла а потом хотите чтобы вам что то вывелось. Поэтому просто переместите break; туда после какого действия/команды вам надо завершить цикл.